# Inserting single item into ListBox from range

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code that from ListBox1 populates ListBox2.  The boxes are populated from a worksheet that has header of names (A:AC) and underneath each name is a list of Ids that will populate into ListBox2.  There could be multiple IDs for each person or some just have one.  My 2 questions are
1.  How can I insert into listbox from a dynamic column
2.  During testing if there is more than one ID it inserts great but if only one ID error.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim myArray As Variant
'pulls selected value from listbox1
myArray = ListBox1.List(ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Columns("A:CC").Select
'looks for selected value from listbox1
Set found = Cells.Find(What:=myArray, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
, SearchFormat:=False)


If found Is Nothing Then
    'skipper
Else
    found.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If

'below is where i tried to assign the column letter to a variable, didn't work
'Col = Split(ActiveCell(1).Address(1, 0), "$")(0)
'Me.ListBox2.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Col & "2:" & Col & Range(Col & Range(Col & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

'belwo works great if more than one ID, otherwise it's crap
Me.ListBox2.List = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Value

End Sub
```

Some progress.  I've got it to find and populate via the dynamic column but still won't work if the range is just a single cell.  Thanks to avb for the bit of code.

```
Else
   Set test = Range(found.Offset(1, 0), found.End(xlDown))
test.Copy
End If

Me.ListBox2.List = test.Value
```

SOLUTION!
What I found out is that if there is only one item selected you need to use the .AddItem as opposed to the .List I was using.  I ended up with this final snippet.

```
Set sId = Range(found.Offset(1, 0), found.End(xlDown))
    sId.Copy

If IsEmpty(found.Offset(2, 0).Value) Then
   With Worksheets("Sheet1")
      Me.ListBox2.AddItem sId
   End With
Else
   Me.ListBox2.List = sId.Value
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

SOLUTION! What I found out is that if there is only one item selected you need to use the .AddItem as opposed to the .List I was using. I ended up with this final snippet.

```
Set sId = Range(found.Offset(1, 0), found.End(xlDown))
    sId.Copy

If IsEmpty(found.Offset(2, 0).Value) Then
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Me.ListBox2.AddItem sId
End With
Else
    Me.ListBox2.List = sId.Value
End If
```

Comment: +1. The `.List` method requires an array. In the case of a single-cell range, `sID` (nor `sID.Value`) is an array. You could test `If sID.cells.Count > 1 then Me.ListBox2.List = sId.Value: Else: Me.ListBox2.AddItem sID`.

Comment: Thanks for clearing up what i found, like your method as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have no blank cells within your Id list this will work:

```
Else
    Me.ListBox2.List = Range(found.Offset(1, 0), found.End(xlDown))
End If
```

Comment: Thanks but i get the error msg Couldn't set the list property, Invalid property array index

Comment: I wrote it out of my head without testing because do not have Excel at home now, try Range(found.Offset(1, 0), found.End(xlDown)).Select and then you will see if the proper range was selected.

Comment: Unfortunately same error.  Thanks though, I'll keep plugging away at it.